# ffmpeg conversion command to output to h.264 for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ffmpeg, video-encoding, h.264

I'm looking for a good (general) conversion command that will convert any input file to h.264 sized for the iPad.

Currently I have this command that works, that was adapted from [robert.swain](http://rob.opendot.cl/index.php/useful-stuff/ipod-video-guide/)

With presets:

```
$ ffmpeg -i INPUT -acodec aac -ab 160000 -s 1024x768 -vcodec libx264 \
         -vpre slow -vpre ipod640 -b 1200kb -threads 0 -f mp4 OUTPUT.mp4
```

Long form, no presets:

```
$ ffmpeg -i INPUT -acodec aac -ab 160000 -s 1024x768 -vcodec libx264 \
         -coder 1 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma \
         -partitions +parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method umh \
         -subq 8 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 \
         -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 2 -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 \
         -bf 3 -refs 5 -directpred 3 -trellis 1 \
         -flags2 +bpyramid+mixed_refs+wpred+dct8x8+fastpskip -wpredp 2 \
         -rc_lookahead 50 -coder 0 -bf 0 -refs 1 -flags2 -wpred-dct8x8 \
         -level 30 -maxrate 10000000 -bufsize 10000000 -wpredp 0 -b 1200k \
         -threads 0 -f mp4 OUTPUT.mp4
```

Note: I'm skipping the aspect ratio because we handle that in the program, and we only resize it if the input resolution is greater than the output resolution.

If there's any suggestions for improvement, we are looking to balance speed, quality and  conversion time.

Comment: Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height :(

Answer (score 10):

Check this link. All the conversion settings you can shake a phone at.
http://develop.participatoryculture.org/index.php/ConversionMatrix

Comment: It seems this website may be outdated.

Comment: Link is dead, what parameters would you recommend?