# Setting of MPMoviePlayerViewController's initialPlaybackTime not working

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using an MPMoviePlayerViewController in my application and I'm trying to set the initial playback time by traversing the view controller's moviePlayer property and then setting the initial playback like so:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* moviePlayerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = 100;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerViewController];
```

Regardless of what I pass in, the movie always starts from the beginning. What am I missing here?

Comment: Give this a try, `[moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer setInitialPlaybackTime:100.0];` Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to Objective-C

Comment: 100 is 1 minute, 40 seconds. How long is your video?

Comment: @0x7fffffff I'm just copying from my video player (which seeks) If this doesn't work, I'd suggest looking at the movieSourceType

Comment: More than 1 minute and 40 seconds.

Comment: Does the video play normally without the `initialPlaybackTime`?

Comment: [Here's a basic version my code if it helps anything](http://pastebin.com/Am8a9M7w) - You should also check the video allows seeking, try with [this file](http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4)

Comment: @JamieTaylor, I just saw this comment. I'll remove my answer if you want me to.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato Don't worry about it, Your code looks more fleshed out anyway :D

Comment: @0x7fffffff, "starts from the beginning" means starts as if there is no initial playback time set.

Comment: It seems as if using MPMoviePlayerViewController doesn't respect the initial playback time set on a movie. If I create a MPMoviePlayerController and add it's view as a subview, setting the initial playback time works. I want to use the presentMoviePlayerViewController method though, so I need to find a way to at least replicate this method if I can't get the MPMoviePlayerViewController to respect the playback time.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of my code with `initialPlaybackTime` working out of the box (simply copy and past code on viewController and play it).

```
    MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMovie =
    [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"]];
    theMovie.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    [theMovie.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, 400.0, 250.0)];
    [theMovie.moviePlayer setInitialPlaybackTime:10];
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
```

If this works for you but your own video doesn't work, theres an issue with the video you are using, I guess.

Comment: If it does turn out to be an issue with the video, get your hands on FFMpeg and give [this a try](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18596085/1400370)